# java permgen out of memory for a swing application on linux but not on windows

Tags: java, swing, exception, out-of-memory

I have a swing application when i run it on windows i have no problem with it but when i run it on linux i get the out of memory permgen exception after few time i am using it.

On windows i use jdk6 update 32 32bit, on linux i use the same jdk 6, same update version but 64bit.

The only thing that change when i run the application on windows/linux is the look and feel, when i run it on windows i use one, when i run it on linux i use another but they are both from jgoodies site.

What it can be the reason for this problem?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Out of interest, are you adjusting the memory allocations at all? Or are they left at the defaults?

Comment: I know i can increase the permgen space but i run it as default as i ran it on windows, the only thing that i increase is the heap space with -Xmx512m

Comment: I think you have to increase the Permgen size when you increase the heap space. Consider this source. http://mark.koli.ch/2009/01/understanding-javas-perm-gen-maxpermsize-heap-space-etc.html

Comment: Sorry maybe i was not clear, i increase heap space in both the situations, when i run it on windows and when i run it on linux but the problem with permgen is present only on linux

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but did you compile your code in windows and linux separately?

Comment: The code is compiled on the windows pc, but i think this doesn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you think this is a Windows versus Linux thing, I think that the more salient difference between the two systems is 32 bit versus 64 bit.

On a 64 bit JVM, references and reference-valued fields occupy twice as many bytes, and padding increases in other cases.  Since a String object includes a reference field, etc, this could be sufficient to make the objects larger.  And that could result in greater PermGen usage if you have lots of String literals or manually interned Strings.

Either way, the obvious solution is to increase the Permgen size via the JVM command line options.  Indeed, apart from figuring out some way to reduce the application's Permgen usage (which may be impractical), this is probably the only solution.

Comment: I see your point, i am not an expert in memory management but this doesn't affect just the heap space?

Comment: By "this", I presume you mean 32 vs 64 bit?  If so, then the answer is that heap management is pretty much the limit of the differences ... unless you've got native code libraries to contend with.  Of source, there may be subtle differences in threading and the memory model, but if your code was correct to start with they shouldn't affect you.